# What tasks does a memory barrier enforces other than preventing the re-ordering of instructions?

Tags: c, multithreading, memory-barriers

I know that a memory barrier prevents the re-ordering of instruction from before to after and from after to before the memory barrier, for example if I have the following instructions:

```
instruction 1
instruction 2
instruction 3
memory barrier
instruction 4
instruction 5
instruction 6
```

These instructions can be executed in the following order:

```
instruction 3
instruction 1
instruction 2
memory barrier
instruction 6
instruction 5
instruction 4
```

But they will never be executed in the following order:

```
instruction 1
instruction 2
instruction 5
memory barrier
instruction 4
instruction 3
instruction 6
```

But I am not sure if the following tasks are also enforced by a memory barrier:

- All pending operations before the memory barrier are completed.
- All data that are still in the cache from write operations before the memory barrier are flushed.

Comment: This is an interesting question but very very broad. Each architecture has its own barriers. In general, neither of your enumerated tasks are mandatory for a barrier.

Answer (score 0):

At least for IBM's powerPC, finishing is not guaranteed, c.f. [IBM's documentation](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/systems/articles/powerpc.html):

> [The] execution or completion of the eieio instruction does not imply that the storage accesses caused by instructions preceding the eieio have completed. The barrier created by the instruction will ensure that all accesses separated by the barrier are performed in the specified order, but accesses issued prior to the barrier might not be performed until long after the eieio instruction completes

Answer (score 0):

Technically a memory barrier does not enforce any order on instruction execution.  It constrains the order in instruction executions become *visible* to other observers.

Flushing to memory is not required, and indeed would greatly slow down cache-based architectures.  For example, consider a core that maintains a private queue of pending memory operations and has a coherent cache shared with other cores.  When it reaches a barrier, it can drain its queue of memory operations before letting any more memory operations into its queue.  It does not have to drain its cache -- cache coherence will deal with the rest.  See [A Primer on Memory Consistency
and Cache Coherence](https://lagunita.stanford.edu/c4x/Engineering/CS316/asset/A_Primer_on_Memory_Consistency_and_Coherence.pdf) for detailed descriptions of how these protocols can work.